# What is the best way to do sequential rest calls in angualarjs

Tags: angularjs

In my application, I have sign page. When user clicks on login button, I have to make three sequential rest calls to check for authentication, getting tasks list and user tasks list. Now, I am using promises to make all rest calls.But, It is taking too longer time to load application. I want to know that, what is the best way to do rest calls that will take minimum amount of time and also wont affects the application performance.

Comment: what serverside platform are you using?

Comment: You cannot avoid the latency of your server calls. However couldn't you do them all in one call to the server? That would save performances and bandwidth. Also, you can probably start to display a few things, or at the very least a loading bar before you have the data back. So run them in parallel, but try not to block the whole application waiting.

Comment: Ruby on rails is server side platform. But, login api response gives me auth token.I ve to call welcome api to get action plan id. then using action plan id, ve to call user action plan (user tasks) and action plans (all tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to return in one response the user tasks and task list? So have them nested.

In my own application I return a nested set of arrays in one response that contain all the data to initialise the display after the users logs in. Thereafter a session sync request is made which just returns any updates in those arrays, again as a single response.

Perhaps going a bit off topic here but do you know if you are or can serve the responses back compressed to the client, thats if the browser supports compression (gzip,deflate)?

Comment: No. not possible. For caching tasks, server team separated user tasks from tasks.